# div content not responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a site that was developed by another person. This site is designed with wordpress by override a base theme(blankslate). This is the link:
http://www.good-look.it
There is a problem. When you resize the browser window you can see that the div with white background is responsive, but its not. On mobile the problem is more visible. I can't find a solution. Maybe is a problem with the plugin that manage the image slides(NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati)?

Comment: Please *read* the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a post in future.  This has nothing to do with the [tag:next-generation-plugin] as defined on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this file: http://www.good-look.it/wp-content/themes/blankslate/css/struttura.css

There are numerous CSS styles with "!important" on them. For example:

```
wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 940px !important;
}
```

The width of this container will always be 940px with the way you have it now. Turning this style off in Firebug "fixed" the "Brands" section. There are numerous problems in the CSS though that will affect responsive behavior.

Comment: thank you! this help me, but on mobile don't work. The white div have a wrong width.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I thing we should be clear that the site is made with html, css, php, js etc --- so WordPress is really pretty irrelevant.

Most of the site isn't really planned in a way that is going to be responsive, but the specific problem of the white div, is that it is responsive, but the slider within - is not responsive, and uses absolute positioning --- so it's position is falling out of the parent div, and then making the content wider than the white div, and therefor wider than the window itself.

Did some quick styles in the inspector --- the slider's actually sorta "responsive."

replace

```
.wrapper {
  width: 960px !important;
  ...
```

with

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  ...
```

and it will get you a little closer...

Answer (score 0):

while designing a responsive site make sure that while defining width use %age instead of pixels like(940px). bcoz it arranges your div in %age according to your current device size but while defining `width:940px` it will take that amount of width irrespective of your screen size...